How to load a file from the BAS type computer and run it as a macro on an Excel file using EPPLUS
I am trying to create a program in C# which imports a module of type bas (saved on the computer) on an Excel file saved on the computer
And it will not be mandatory to have Microsoft Office installed on the computer.
I am using the Epplus library for Excel. I saw that it is suggested to import and create a VBA file and then insert the basd code. I haven't found how to do it exactly.
Before that I imported a CSV file and created an Excel file from it and on this Excel (sheet1). I need to run a module.
I don't know how to import the bas file and run it in the module
Would appreciate help
var file11 = new FileInfo(@"C:\\Users\\master\\Tochniot_Kshurot.csv");
// using var package11 = new ExcelPackage();
var sheet1 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
var ts = TableStyles.Dark1;
sheet1.Cells\["A1"\].LoadFromText(file11, format11, ts, FirstRowIsHeader: true);

string basFilePath = "M:/Module1.bas";
string excelFilePath = @"C:\\Users\\2.3-sheet.xlsx";
var basCode = new FileInfo(basFilePath);

package.Workbook.CodeModule.Code = basCode.ToString();
var codeModule = new CodeModule(basCode);

var result = codeModule.Run(sheet1);
var data = worksheet.Cells.ToJaggedArray\<object\>();

I can't find the code anymore. I tried to import and create a VBA file and add as a module and run, but didn't work.
